# Error trying to access /token in web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to host a web Api project with angularjs, with authentication.
It works well on local but when i run it from live it can't find ../token method used for generating token and returns 404 error.

I have tried everything but still no use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please show us sample code for what you are working with and what you have tried